# Using regex to see if a number is in a string before others?

Tags: python

I am new to python, so obviously as well to using regex. I am just curious if it is possible to see if a number is inputted before other numbers in a string?

What this function(def checkzero) should be doing is checking to see if 0 is inputted before another number, and if it is then return True (For invalid)

```
import string
import re

plate_pattern = re.compile('\D*\d*')


def main():
    plate = input("Plate: ")
    tests = [exclusions, platecheck, checkzero]
    invalid = any(test(plate) for test in tests)
    if invalid:
        print("Invalid \nNo numbers in the start/middle of the plate, first number may not be 0. \nNo punctuation allowed.\nPlate must be between 2-6 characters.")
    else:
        print("Valid")


def exclusions(s):
    if any(c in string.punctuation for c in s):
        return True
    return len(s) > 6 or len(s) < 2


def platecheck(s):
    return not plate_pattern.fullmatch(s)


def checkzero(s):
    # Not sure how to go about creating the function to check if zero is inputted before other numbers.
    pass


main()
```

Example of Input/Output:

Input:

```
test02
```

Output:

```
Invalid
...
```

Input:

```
test20
```

Output:

```
Valid
```

Comment: Can you explain, what should be the output, when input is ```test002``` and ```test2022```?

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin 002 would be Invalid, it can't start with a 0 at all,  "te2022" would be fine even though the output test2022 would still be invalid since over 6 characters.

Comment: what if it's just ```test0```?

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin Invalid, the first number at any point can not be 0.

Comment: @BhusalC_Bipin of course! There is a slight issue with the current answer though it is returning test0 as valid.

Comment: I have added my solution, please do check it and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Revision in response to comment

> The first number at any point can not be 0

You could look from the start of the string `^` for non-digit characters `[^\d]*` and then a 0 perhaps followed by a digit `.*\d?`, then proceed the same from there (also updated test cases):

````py
def checkzero(s):
    p = re.compile(r"^[^\d]*0.*\d?")
    matched = re.search(p, s)
    return re.search(p, s) != None
    
test_cases = ["test0", "test1", "test01", "test10", "test101"]

for test in test_cases:
    print(test, end = ": ")
    if checkzero(test):
        print("Matched, INVALID")
    else:
        print("Not matched, VALID")```
````

Output:

```
test0: Matched, INVALID
test1: Not matched, VALID
test01: Matched, INVALID
test10: Not matched, VALID
test101: Not matched, VALID
```

### Original Post

You could use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search). If a match is found, then a `Match` object will be returned, otherwise `None` will be returned.

```py
def checkzero(s):
    p = re.compile(r"0.*\d")
    matched = re.search(p, s)
    return re.search(p, s) != None
```

*Note: if you want the 0 to be immediately followed by a digit, remove the `.*` in the regex expression*

Comment: The original post really needs more test cases. These all show as valid with your code: `test_cases = ['test01020304','test9080706','90807060test','01020304test']`

Comment: Well all your test cases have 0 before another digit, I think we just interpreted the question differently

Comment: No this does work whenever implemented into the full code, I already have a function that checks to see if 0 is inputted first than it is invalid, which is platecheck, actually... There is an issue, if I do test0 it's testing valid.

Comment: @Blue Updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 2):

So to make it simple, we are just checking, if first occurence of a digit in given string is `0` or not.

```py
import re

def checkzero(s):
    return re.search(r'\d', s).group() == '0'
```

Test:

```py
test_cases = ['test0', 'test02', 'test20', 'test002', 'test2022']
for test_case in test_cases:
    print(checkzero(test_case))
```

Output:

```py
>>> True
>>> True
>>> False
>>> True
>>> False
```